# Does windows azure virtual machine logs out when disconnecting

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I use windows azure virtual machine. I have a few programs running, but in the future, they have to run non-stop.
If I disconnect from my virtual machine, will the virtual machine log out/shut down?
I have essential programs running, and if they stop running, it will be a huge problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your Virtual Machines don't shut down when you disconnect from rdp/ssh. However: There's always the possibility that your machine will restart, even if infrequently (e.g. failed hardware, Host OS maintenance, etc.). So... your essential programs should be set up to auto-start at boot time, without requiring you to rdp/ssh in to start them up again.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciated your answer.
Have a nice day